# Using ccache when cross-compiling with autotools

Tags: cross-compiling, autotools, configure, autoconf, ccache

I know the standard way of cross compiling an autoconf-based project:

$ ./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32

However, what if I want to use ccache?

I know I can override the CC and CXX variables (e.g CC="ccache i686-w64-mingw32-gcc" ./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32). However, this seems redundant and error prone.

Is there a standard way, I'm missing, like some CC_PREFIX variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't, if you want to use ccache you'll have to change your `CC`/`CXX` parameters as well as passing `--host`.

By the way, prefer

```
./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 \
    CC="ccache i686-w64-mingw32-gcc" CXX="ccache i686-w64-mingw32-g++"
```

rather than pre-fixing the environment variables. This way they will be correctly recorded as overrides in `config.log`/`config.cache` if you're using maintainer mode.

Answer (score -1):

The best way I found (and which I'm using now) is to use symlinks and PATH magic:

> $ which -a gcc
>
> /usr/lib/ccache/gcc
>
> /usr/bin/gcc

This way, no special option is needed when invoking ./configure, who can't even see that ccache exists in this build.